# Sublime Text 3: how to assign default encoding for a file type? (creation of custom file type)

Tags: sublime-text-3

In order to work with files faster, I need to open some of them in a specific encoding depending on the file type.
The only solution I found was [this](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11688), but the topic starter needed something different than I am and his solution won't wok for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. create a copy of `Text.sublime-package` from `Package` folder that is in `Program Files` (of course, if you use Windows);
2. unzip `Text.sublime-package`;
3. rename `Plain text.tmLanguage` to `EXT.tmLanguage`;
4. edit `EXT.tmLanguage` by modifying "content" of two keys: `fileTypes` and `name`. E.g., in my case edited XML looked like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>fileTypes</key>
       <array>
           <string>ascii</string>
           <string>nfo</string>
       </array>

       <key>name</key>
       <string>ASCII art</string>

       <key>patterns</key>
       <array>
       </array>

       <key>scopeName</key>
       <string>text.plain</string>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
5. zip `EXT.tmLanguage` (it seems that you may use compression);
6. rename archive into `EXT.sublime-package`.

After that do as Mrsonord have described:

1. go to `Preferences > Settings – More > Syntax Specific – User`;
2. in newly opened file paste the string below (in my case `SublimeEncodingName` was `DOS (CP 437)`):

   ```
   {
       "default_encoding": "%SublimeEncodingName%",
       "fallback_encoding": "%SublimeEncodingName%",
   }
   ```
3. save the file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Either:

   - Browse packages and create a file EXT.sublime-settings(Note the caps on filetype ext).
   - While editing the filetype you wish to modify settings for: Preferences->Settings - More->Syntax Specific - User
2. Enter your desired encoding options as the example below.

> `{
>       "default_encoding": "UTF-8",
>       "fallback_encoding": "utf-8"
>    }`

Comment: It doesn't work. When I'm opening my file, which by default is `Plain text`, and run command `Syntax Specific - User` file `EXT.sublime-settings` is created automatically, but it is of the type `Plain text`. When I manually create `EXT.sublime-settings` nothing happens as well. The only possible solution I've found (haven't tested) is to create new syntax file in Program Files under `Packages`, like `Markdown.sublime-package` (zipped file with XML describing settings for the file type).